# What does it mean to call a module with parameters "python mymod.py 50"?

Tags: python, module

What does it mean to call a module with parameters
`python mymod.py 50`?

What does it mean and what will happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply means you pass `50` as string parameter to the python script `mymod.py`.

Below is a sample code of `mymod.py` to show what will happen.

```
import sys

print("Hello World")

print(sys.argv)

if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print(sys.argv[1])
```

You could copy this code snippet into `mymod.py` and test in your PC by running

```
python mymod.py 50
```

and you may get result like the following:

```
Hello World
['test.py', '50']
50
```

As a result, in `mymod.py` we could get the passed parameter from the built-in `sys.argv` var.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, Lauren. If it helps please adopt my answer as I am trying to get my first reputations. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically running the file mymod.py by passing parameter from the command line. In this case value of the parameter is 50. The way that parameter will be handled will depend upon the code written inside mymod.py